# How to connect to an existing wifi network

Tags: wireless, lubuntu

I just changed from Windows XP to Lubuntu, I have used Ubuntu in the past when I was a child but it used a ethernet cord to connect. How do I connect to Wifi using my laptop (Lubuntu)? I can't figure out how to connect to or even view available networks. The simpler the answer the better.

Answer (score 0):

If you have NetworkManager applet running - then you should have an icon in taskbar. Righ click - and ensure that nm-applet controls the network and the wireless network in particular. Then setup wireless connections.

You can check that you have `nm-applet` running with this command:

```
$ ps -AF | grep nm-applet
azure     2290     1  0 210160 20252  0 17:03 ?        00:00:00 nm-applet
azure     6290  6267  0  4342   904   0 23:21 pts/5    00:00:00 grep --color=auto nm-applet
```

Note: latest lxde environment in ubuntu failed to run nm-applet because console kit session was not launched by login manager :\ I resolved this by switching to kdm.

Comment: I can open both of the network applets the Network Connections and the Network Settings ones but I input as much information as I can (the SSID the security type as in wpa or wpa2 etc. the network type AD-HOC and the password) but it still won't connect to the Routers Singnal.